# How to show certain items only in a ListView?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

My code shows all the contacts in a `ListView`, what I want is to be able to display only contacts that contain the words "**Ben**" and "**Dover**" in them.

Example:

- **Ben** plumber
- Lenovo **ben**
- **Dover** church

**Here is my complete code:**

```
public class Contacts extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;
ArrayList<String> StoreContacts;
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
Cursor cursor;
String name, phonenumber;
public static final int RequestPermissionCode = 1;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    StoreContacts = new ArrayList<String>();
    EnableRuntimePermission();
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            GetContactsIntoArrayList();
            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    Contacts.this,
                    R.layout.contact_items_listview,
                    R.id.textView, StoreContacts
            );
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }
    });
}

public void GetContactsIntoArrayList() {
    cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        phonenumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        StoreContacts.add(name + " " + ":" + " " + phonenumber);
    }
    cursor.close();
}

public void EnableRuntimePermission() {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Contacts.this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {
        Toast.makeText(Contacts.this, "CONTACTS permission allows us to Access CONTACTS app", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Contacts.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, RequestPermissionCode);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int RC, String per[], int[] PResult) {
    switch (RC) {
        case RequestPermissionCode:
            if (PResult.length > 0 && PResult[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(Contacts.this, "Permission Granted, Now your application can access CONTACTS.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(Contacts.this, "Permission Canceled, Now your application cannot access CONTACTS.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Consider using Regex

Comment: @amtrax Dziękuję Ci, proszę podać przykład.